# Problems when trying to run a .exe File which was made by using PyInstaller

Tags: python-2.7

I wrote a Python Script which uses Oauth2 to get some data from the YouTube analytics API. Now I have converted it into an exe File with PythonInstaller but when I try to run the exe file I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 225, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 101, in main
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\oauth2client.util", line 132, in positional_wrapper
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\apiclient.discovery", line 192, in build
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\oauth2client.util", line 132, in positional_wrapper
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\oauth2client.client", line 490, in new_request
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib2", line 1570, in request
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib2", line 1317, in _request
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib2", line 1252, in _conn_request
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib2", line 1021, in connect
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\httplib2", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 387, in wrap_socket
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Caspar\PyInstaller-2.1\GetYoutubeViews\build\Get
YoutubeViews\out00-PYZ.pyz\ssl", line 141, in __init__
  ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:343: error:0B084002:x509 certificate rout
  ines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```